# How can I delay animation depending on item index

Tags: wpf, listview, animation, indexing, delay

I have animations on items in a listview, but they are not played with order. They all play on same time. How can i add delay to animations depending on item index?

Comment: any code you have tried ?

Comment: I didn't try anything since you cannot do math with wpf.

Comment: nothing is impossible ?

Comment: if you can visual show me what you want i will do that

Comment: @MeerDeen Showing as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could call the animation.completed() method on the animation so that each animation starts when the previous animation finished

Comment: I want delay, not run with chain.